# What is more efficient: vector.clear() or if(vector.empty()) clear();?

Tags: c++, std

As the subject states.. which version is more efficient and why?

```
std::vector a;
..

a.clear();
```

or

```
std::vector a;
..
if(!a.empty())
  a.clear();
```

Comment: Try profiling & you'll get the answer.

Comment: **They don't do the same thing**. What kind of question is this?

Comment: Clearing a vector only when it is empty is likely faster than also clearing it when it has entries :) I think you mean `if(!a.empty())`

Comment: What's the point of clearing if `a` is empty? Besides that, this is implementation defined, and this kind of micro optimization should almost never concern you in a real life application

Comment: Did you leave out a "!"?

Comment: Efficiency over what metric? Maintainability? Lines of code? Hourly wage? Size?

Comment: @doctorlove yes, sorry everyone :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An empty vector is a valid vector. So the operation

```
a.clear();
```

is valid on an empty vector.

Test for emptiness before clear is unnecessary and time consuming, so the first one is more efficient.

Comment: And a bit pointless if you only try to clear it when it's already empty.

Answer (score 12):

Efficiency aside, the fact that you managed to write a bug into this tiny snippet is proof that the first version is far superior. The less complicated the code, the better.

Comment: I'm capable of incredible tasks... sorry :D